# Is there any way to retrieve inserted rows of a command

Tags: sql-server-2005

We probably all know `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to retrieve the identity generated by a single insert. Currently I'm in the need of some kind of magic variable or function to retrieve all the rows generated by a statement, eg:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[myMagicTable]
(
    [name]
)
SELECT    [name]
FROM      [dbo].[myMagicSource]
WHERE     /* some weird where-clauses with several subselects ... */;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[myMagicBackupTable]
(
    [id],
    [name]
)
SELECT
    [id],
    [name]
FROM    ???
```

An insert trigger is no option, as this will perform a single insert which is a problem for a batch of 10.000 rows...
So, is there any way to achieve this?
We are using mssql2005<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+, you can use the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

```
DECLARE @InsertedIDs table(ID int);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[myMagicTable]
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
        INTO @InsertedIDs 
    SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a temporary table (possibly a table variable) and make use of the `OUTPUT` clause on your INSERT (you can make use of the `Inserted` pseudo-table, like in a trigger):

```
DECLARE @NewIDs TABLE (MagicID INT, Name VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[myMagicTable]([name])
OUTPUT Inserted.MagicID, Inserted.Name INTO @NewIDs(MagicID, Name)
  SELECT    [name]
  FROM      [dbo].[myMagicSource]
  WHERE     /
```

and then use that table variable after the INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO 
  [dbo].[myMagicBackupTable]([id], [name])
  SELECT MagicID, [name]
  FROM @NewIDs
```

and go from there.